# Mysql filter double dates

Tags: mysql

I am busy writing a php program to check which products have being sold on a specific date.

Now i am facing the problem that the same date is being put into the database multiple times.

So when i want to read all the dates i see some dates displaying like 10 times.

This is the query :

```
SELECT date
FROM sales 
ORDER BY date DESC
```

I have being looking on the internet for a while now, but i cant seem to find it.

If someone would give me a little hand that would be great.

Thanks in forehand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [DISTINCT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/distinct-optimization.html):

```
SELECT DISTINCT date
FROM sales 
ORDER BY date DESC;
```

Answer (score 1):

Two ways. Either use [SELECT DISTINCT](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp) or the [GroupBy](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp)-Statement.